# TCP chat in c not reading/sending strings correctly

Tags: c, string, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to implement a multi-client chat, using tcp socket-based connections and threads to manage the clients and inputs. However the reading and writing of the sent or received string aren't being executed correctly, and i can't quite figure out why.

Server:

```
#define IP "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 9000
#define MAX_CONNECTION_Q 10
#define CLIENTS 10
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define NAMELEN 32
#define COMMANDS 16
#define MESSAGESIZE 256
#define LINENUM 512

struct chat{
  char userlist[CLIENTS][NAMELEN];
  char admin[NAMELEN];
  char ID[NAMELEN];
  char logg[512][216];
  struct chat *next;
  int pos;
};

struct client_info{
  pthread_t client_ID;
  int sockfd;
  struct chat chats;
  char user[NAMELEN];
  struct client_info *next;
};

struct header{
  struct client_info *fnode, *lnode;
}*client_head;

struct chat_head{
  struct chat *fnode,*lnode;
}*chat_head;


int sockfd, clinfo;
struct client_info thread_info[CLIENTS];
struct header client_list;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void list_init() {
  client_head = malloc(sizeof(struct header));
  chat_head = malloc(sizeof(struct chat_head));
  client_head->fnode = NULL;
  chat_head->fnode = NULL;
}

int compare(int a, int b){
  return (a-b);
}

void chat_insert(struct chat *node){
  if(chat_head->fnode == NULL){
    chat_head->fnode = node;
    chat_head->lnode = node;
  }
  else{
    chat_head->lnode->next = node;
    chat_head->lnode = node;
  }
}

int search_cli(char *name){
  struct client_info *tmp = client_head->fnode;
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    if(strcmp(tmp->user,name) == 0){
      return tmp->sockfd;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
  return -1;
}

void client_insert(struct client_info *node){
  if(client_head->fnode == NULL){
    client_head->fnode = node;
    client_head->lnode = node;
    node->next = NULL;
  }
  else{
    client_head->lnode->next = node;
    client_head->lnode = node;
    node->next = NULL;
  }
}

void client_delete(struct client_info *node){
  struct client_info *last = client_head->fnode;
  struct client_info *tmp = last->next;
  if(client_head->fnode == NULL){
    return;
  }
  if(compare(last->sockfd, node->sockfd) == 0){
    client_head->fnode = tmp;

    free(last);

    if(client_head->fnode == NULL){

      client_head->lnode = NULL;

    }

    return;
  }
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    if(compare(tmp->sockfd, node->sockfd) == 0) {
      last->next = tmp->next;

      free(tmp);
      return;
    }

    tmp = tmp->next;
  }

}

void display_clients(){
  struct client_info *tmp = client_head->fnode;
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    printf("Username: %s\nSocket: %d\n--------------------\n",tmp->user,tmp->sockfd);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}

void change_username(int sock,char *sender){
  struct client_info *tmp = client_head->fnode;
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    if(tmp->sockfd == sock){
      strcpy(tmp->user,sender);
      break;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}

void *client_commands_handler(void *fd){
  struct client_info *clinfo = (struct client_info *)fd;
  char *buffer = malloc(NAMELEN);
  char receiver[NAMELEN],sender[NAMELEN],message[BUFFSIZE];
  recv(clinfo->sockfd,buffer,NAMELEN,0);
  strcpy(clinfo->user,buffer);
  memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
  int nbytes;
  while(1){
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    nbytes = recv(clinfo->sockfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0);
    if(nbytes<=0) {
      printf("%s lost connection\n", clinfo->user);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      client_delete(clinfo);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      break;
    }
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    else if(strncmp(buffer, "private", 7) == 0) {
      int sockid;
      sscanf(buffer,"private %s %s %s",sender,receiver,message);
      printf("%s%s%s",sender,receiver,message);
      if((sockid = search_cli(sender)) == -1){
        char *server = malloc(NAMELEN);
        strcpy(server,"<Server> User doesn't exist\n");
        write(clinfo->sockfd,server,strlen(server));
      }
      else{
        struct chat new_chat;
        new_chat.pos = 0;
        strcpy(new_chat.logg[new_chat.pos],message);
        new_chat.pos++;
        strcpy(new_chat.userlist[0],sender);
        strcpy(new_chat.userlist[1],receiver);           
      sprintf(new_chat.ID,"%s%s",new_chat.userlist[0],new_chat.userlist[1]);
        new_chat.next = NULL;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        chat_insert(&new_chat);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        send(sockid,message,strlen(message),0);
      }
    }
    else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Garbage data from [%d] %s...\n", clinfo->sockfd, clinfo->user);
    }
  }
  close(clinfo->sockfd);
  return NULL;
}

void *server_commands_handler() {

}

int main() {
  int size,clientfd;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
  pthread_t server_commands;
  list_init();
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Couldn't get server socket");
    exit(0);
  }
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
  memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Couldn't bind socket");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(listen(sockfd, MAX_CONNECTION_Q) == -1){
    perror("Couldn't listen");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(pthread_create(&server_commands, NULL, *server_commands_handler, NULL) != 0){
    perror("Couldn't create thread");
    exit(0);
  }
  while(1){
    size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if((clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)&size))==-1){
      perror("Connection failed");
      exit(0);
    }
    printf("Client accepted\n");
    struct client_info clinfo;
    clinfo.sockfd = clientfd;
    clinfo.next = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    client_insert(&clinfo);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&clinfo.client_ID, NULL, client_commands_handler, (void *)&clinfo);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

client:

```
#define SERVERIP "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVERPORT 9000
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define USERLEN 32
#define OPTLEN 16

struct threadinfo{
  pthread_t thread_ID;
  int sockfd;
};

struct USER{
  char user[USERLEN];
  int sockfd;
  char current_convo[USERLEN];
};

int isconnected, sockfd, sent;
char option[BUFFSIZE];
struct USER me;

int connect_with_server();
void logout(struct USER *me);
void login(struct USER *me);
void *receiver();

void login(struct USER *me){
  if(isconnected){
    printf("Already connected\n");
    return;
  }
  sockfd = connect_with_server();
  if(sockfd == -1){
    perror("Couldn't connect to server\n");
  }
  if(sockfd >= 0) {
    isconnected = 1;
    me->sockfd = sockfd;
    printf("Logged in as %s\n", me->user);
    struct threadinfo thread;
    pthread_create(&thread.thread_ID, NULL, receiver, (void *)&thread);
  }
  else {
    printf("Couldn't connect.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
}

void *receiver(){
  int recvd;
  char msg[BUFFSIZE];
  while(isconnected){
    memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
    recvd = read(sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
      if(!recvd) {
        printf("Connection Lost from Server\n");
        isconnected = 0;
        close(sockfd);
        break;
      }
      if(recvd > 0) {
        fputs(msg,stdout);
      }
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
    memset(&me, 0, sizeof(struct USER));
    char msg[BUFFSIZE];
    char *token;
    while(fgets(option,BUFFSIZE-1,stdin)){
      memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
      if(strncmp(option,"exit", 4) == 0){
        logout(&me);
        break;
      }
      else if(strncmp(option, "login", 5) == 0){
        token = strtok(option, " ");
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        memset(me.user, 0, sizeof(char)*USERLEN);
        if(token != NULL) {
          strcpy(me.user, token);
          login(&me);
        }
        else{
          printf("Couldn't get valid username\n");
        }
      }
      else if(strncmp(option, "private", 7) == 0){
        if(isconnected == 0){
          printf("User not connected\n");
        }
        else{
          char *tmp = malloc(USERLEN);
          token = strtok(option, " ");
          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
          strcpy(tmp,token);
          token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
          sprintf(msg,"private %s %s %s",me.user,tmp,token);
          send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg),0);
        }
      }
  return 0;
}
```

the code has a lot o code unnecessary to a simple two-way input based connection, however it will have more feature in the long haul that i'm trying to implement.There are many thing to fix here but my question is mainly focused towards sending a string through the "private" input that should be as follows:

> private (username of receiver) (message to send)

Comment: What what exactly the NOT CORRECT behavior is ?

Comment: @potato well it's somewhat unpredictable, but what i'm referring to is not printing the message right or just after an unrelated input, it print the message, and many variations of that.

Comment: how about clearing the buffer memset( msg, 0, sizeof(msg)); before recvd = read(sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));

Comment: @potato added that and it kinda helped. Now it prints on the client the string correctly but i have to enter an input for it to register. I send a message, the other client receives it, but i have to write something on that clients terminal to print the sent message.

Comment: How about a  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Sniper yeah i knew this was going to be a problem, but wanted to give a functional code so that people could try it... Anyway i cut a bunch of code.

Comment: 'memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));' is a waste of cycles and wont help if a full buffer of text is read .  The value of 'recvd', if positive, tells you where to put the NUL in the buffer. You just need to oversize the buffer by one or under-read by one to ensure that there is space for the extra NUL, (eg. 'recvd = read(sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);'.....msg[recvd]=0;).

Comment: You might use Wireshark to verify whether the correct content is sent "over the wire". If yes, check the receiver. If no, check the sender.

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking at it but I noticed a few things.  In your server, you have

```
  char *buffer = malloc(NAMELEN);
  char receiver[NAMELEN],sender[NAMELEN],message[BUFFSIZE];
  recv(clinfo->sockfd,buffer,NAMELEN,0);
  strcpy(clinfo->user,buffer);
  memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
  int nbytes;
  while(1){
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    nbytes = recv(clinfo->sockfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0);
```

The buffer variable receives a pointer to a block of NAMELEN (32) bytes.  You recv NAMELEN bytes without looking at the status.  So far so good.  You then clear the first sizeof buffer bytes (since buffer is a pointer, you are clearing 4 or 8 bytes).  A short time later, you recv BUFFSIZE (1024) bytes into your poor 32 byte buffer.

What I would suggest is you get the server running by testing with telnet

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
```

and typing what your program expects. Keep in mind that the data is only transmitted when you hit return.

The client could be similarly exercised with netcat with:

```
nc -l 127.0.0.1 9000
```

While I am at it, why is your client multithreaded? It would simplify things if you called receiver() directly rather than creating another thread.

Also keep an eye on your mallocs and make sure they are paired with a free. I see a number of places where you malloc a fixed size block of memory and then to do not free it.  This could be accomplished a lot cleaner with a local variable.  Those go away when you return.  Alternatively, look into alloca(), that also goes away when you return.  It is not available everywhere but it is pretty useful.